# Magento 2 - checkout_cart_save_after item price update issue

Tags: magento-2.1

I am using event - checkout_cart_save_after to update cart item's price.
But Item price is not getting updated.

Below is the code.

```
foreach ($observer->getCart()->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    if ($item->getParentItem()) {
        $item = $item->getParentItem();
    }

    $item_price = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();

    $price_for_tier = $item_price + 50;

    $item->setCustomPrice($price_for_tier);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price_for_tier);
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
}
```

Comment: Check first  observer class is call or not?

Comment: yes its getting called. I can echo price.

Comment: Try it with checkout_cart_product_add_after event.

Comment: I tried. It will update only one item price and not all

Comment: You can get cart items like this 
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
$item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item ); 
After you can use $item in foreach.

Comment: How to use $item in for each? Tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with below code -

```
$cart = $observer->getData('cart');

$quote = $cart->getData('quote');

$items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach($items as $item)
{
    $item->setCustomPrice(0);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice(0);
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    $item->save();
}
$quote->save();
$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you see "sales_order_item" item table in Database then you can find below fields which are related to price

```
"price"
"base_price"
"original_price"
"base_original_price"
"price_incl_tax"
"base_price_incl_tax"
```

So you can use like below

```
$item->setPrice();
$item->setBasePrice();
$item->setOriginalPrice();
$item->setOriginalBasePrice();
$item->setPriceInclTax();
$item->setBasePriceInclTax();
```

Please Note: You also need to other filed like "raw_total","base_row_total" etc.